# Key is not found in resource dictionary Exception - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app. I'm unable to set the style from code behind. The following code is inside the constructor of my page.

```
Style greenButton = new Style(typeof(Button))
{
    Setters =
    {
        new Setter{Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Green },
        new Setter{Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Red}
    }
};

Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
Resources.Add(greenButton);

Button createSL = new Button();
createSL.Text = "Create Stack Layout";
createSL.Style = (Style) Resources["greenButton"];
```

The above code gives this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTvE5.png).

> A Key not found Exception stating that 'greenButton' is not present
>   in the dictionary.

But I've done everything as mentioned in the Xamarin.Forms documentation. Kindly help me fix it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Resources.Add` needs to include the text-based name of the style in order to retrieve it by name:

i.e.

```
Resources.Add ("greenButton", greenButton);
```